# phpMyAdmin - 1064 error when executing query

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to execute a query in phpMyAdmin but it is giving me an error saying:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')
>       REFERENCES `Online Shopping`.`Customer` ()
>       ON DELETE NO ACTION
>       ' at line 11

The query is :

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Online Shopping`.`Order_Details` (
  `Order_Id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `Product_Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Price_For_Each_Product` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `No_of_Product_ordered` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Ordered_Date` DATE NULL ,
  `Total_Price` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Generated_Key` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order_Id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `Customer_Id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `Online Shopping`.`Customer` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Order_LineId`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `Online Shopping`.`Order_Line` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax at line 11.

Comment: sorry, I couldn't find any error

Comment: You have to specify foreign key column, e.g. `FOREIGN KEY (column-name)`.

Comment: Read docs : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Online Shopping`.`Order_Details` (
  `Order_Id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Product_Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Price_For_Each_Product` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `No_of_Product_ordered` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Ordered_Date` DATE NULL ,
  `Total_Price` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Generated_Key` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `Customer_Id`
    FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
    REFERENCES `Online Shopping`(Customer)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Order_LineId`
    FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID)
    REFERENCES `Online Shopping`(Order_Line)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```